# How to make pytest run doctests as well as normal tests directory?

Tags: python, testing, pytest, doctest

We currently have `pytest` with the coverage plugin running over our tests in a `tests` directory.

What's the simplest way to also run doctests extracted from our main code?  `--doctest-modules` doesn't work (probably since it just runs doctests from `tests`).  Note that we want to include doctests in the same process (and not simply run a separate invocation of `py.test`) because we want to account for doctest in code coverage.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Now it is implemented :-).

To use, either run `py.test --doctest-modules` command, or set your configuration with `pytest.ini`:

```
$ cat pytest.ini
# content of pytest.ini
[pytest]
addopts = --doctest-modules
```

Man page: [PyTest: doctest integration for modules and test files.](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/doctest.html)

Comment: that doesn't work for us, where we want to specify that tests are in `mypackage/tests` and doctests are e.g. in `mypackage/foo`. What _does_ work is `pytest mypackage/tests --doctest-modules mypackage/foo`. How would one define that in `pytest.ini`? I've tried to express this there, but no cigar.

Comment: @PierreD thanks for sharing your workaround. Didn't have such file structure. Few ideas: once you have the working command-line I would try to move it to `pytest.ini`, like `addopts = --doctest-modules mypackage/foo` and see if it works. I would play with `--doctest-glob="foo/*.txt" to try to catch your files. 
If you would provide a git-repo with the filestructure + requirements.txt, and the result you want to have, one can fix it for your case much faster, I hope.

Comment: well, my comment was wrong; it does what I want but for the wrong reasons: both tests and doctests are collected from both pathes. I was able to further tweak the pytest invocation in our Makefile, but it doesn't quite do what I want (we also have integration tests and integration-lite tests). Bottom-line, what I would need is a way to tell pytest to collect doctests and the regular test collection from potentially two different sets of directories. For example: doctests on everything (`./mypackage`), and tests only from the non-integration tests (`./mypackage/tests`).

Answer (score 2):

This is how I integrate `doctest` in a `pytest` test file:

```py
import doctest
from mylib import mymodule

def test_something():
   """some regular pytest"""
   foo = mymodule.MyClass()
   assert foo.does_something() is True

def test_docstring():
   doctest_results = doctest.testmod(m=mymodule)
   assert doctest_results.failed == 0
```

`pytest` will fail if `doctest` fails and the terminal will show you the `doctest` report.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try with the repo version of pytest and paste a session log?  I'd think `--doctest-modules` should pick up any .py files.

Answer (score 0):

worked with doctest as well as with plain tests in one module. for a non-doctest test to be picked up, standard py.test discovery mechanism applies: a module name with test prefix, test function with test prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Looks old question but put my answer here just in case.

- pytest only run tests in /*test*.py AFAIK and you need to customze with this behavior by the configurations, testpaths and python_files to run doctest in your python code files. seealso: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html#changing-naming-conventions and so on.
- pytest does not run doctest by default and you have to give the option --doctest-modules when running pytest. seealso: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/doctest.html