# How to run all doctests in a folder recursively in pycharm?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm, doctest

Pycharm is great for running all of the doctests per (script / function / class / folder*) but the folder option runs all doctests which are immediately within that folder (not within folders of that folder).

Is there a way to recursively run through some top level folder and run all doctests found?

Comment: sorry, this is almost a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17056138/how-to-make-py-test-run-doctests-as-well-as-normal-tests-directory

Comment: this question is dfferent, it is about pycharm, the other one is not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done from PyCharm with the help of [`pytest`](https://pytest.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

1. If you don't already have it, install `pytest` by running `pip install -U pytest`
2. In PyCharm go to **Run** --> **Edit configurations**
3. Add a new configuration by clicking the **+** button
4. From the pop-up menu, choose **Python tests** --> **py.test**
5. Add `--doctest-modules` to the **Additional Arguments** field
6. Click OK

Now running the newly created configuration will discover and run all doctests, even those in subdirectories.

See [PyCharm's documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-run-debug-configuration-for-tests.html) for more configuration options.