# How to let pytest discover and run doctests in installed modules?

Tags: python, testing, pytest, doctest, tox

I am adding unit tests and to a kind of "legacy" Python package. Some of the modules contain their own doctests embedded in docstrings. My goal is to run both those doctests and new, dedicated unit tests.

Following [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17056138/how-to-make-py-test-run-doctests-as-well-as-normal-tests-directory) ("How to make py.test run doctests as well as normal tests directory?") I'm using the [`--doctest-modules`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/doctest.html) option to `pytest`.  When running from the source repository, `pytest` indeed discovers the embedded doctests from Python modules under the `src` directory.

However, my goal is to test that the source distribution builds and installs at all, and then test everything against the *installed* package. To do this I'm using `tox` which automate the process of building a `sdist` (source distribution) tarball, installing it in a virtual environment, and running the tests against the installed version. To ensure that it is the installed version, rather than the one in the source repository, that is imported by the tests, I follow the suggestion [in this article](https://hynek.me/articles/testing-packaging/) and the repository looks like this now:

```
repo/
  src/
    my_package/
      __init__.py
      module_a.py
      module_b.py
      ...
  tests/
    test_this.py
    test_that.py
  requirements.txt
  setup.py
  tox.ini
```

(The test scripts under `tests` import the package as in `import my_package`, which hits the installed version, because the repository layout makes sure that the `src/my_package` directory is out of the module search paths.)

And in the `tox` configuration file, the relevant sections looks like

```
[tox]
envlist = py27,py36,coverage-report

[testenv]
deps =
  -rrequirements.txt
commands =
  coverage run -p -m pytest --

[pytest]                                                                        
addopts = --doctest-modules
```

So far, the tests run fine, and the doctests are picked up -- from the modules under `src/my_package`, rather than from the package installed in `tox` virtual environments.

My questions related to this set-up is as follows:

- Is this actually a concern? `tox` seems to ensure that what you install is what you have in the source repository, but does it?
- How can I instruct `pytest` to actually run doctests from the installed modules in a sort of clean way? I can think of a few solutions such as building a dedicated documentation tree in a `doc` directory and let `pytest` find the doctests in there with the `--doctest-glob` option. But is there a method to do this without building the docs first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question.

To quote `pytest` [issue #2042](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/2042#issuecomment-381309723):

> currently `doctest-modules` is fundamentally incompatible with testing
>   against a installed package due to module search in checkout vs module
>   usage from `site-packages`

So as of now the solution does not exist.

Comment: Almost 3 years later... No updates? Any alternative to get it on a namespace package?

Answer (score 1):

`pytest` collects tests from *the current directory* (unless you instruct it otherwise passing an explicit directory). Add the installation directory using [tox substitutions](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#substitutions-for-virtualenv-related-sections) in `tox.ini`. I.e., either pass the directory:

```
[testenv]
deps =
  -rrequirements.txt
commands =
  coverage run -p -m pytest {envsitepackagesdir}/my_package
```

or change directory:

```
[testenv]
changedir = {envsitepackagesdir}/my_package
deps =
  -rrequirements.txt
commands =
  coverage run -p -m pytest --
```

Comment: I guess this could have worked if the tests are part of the source distribution, but they're not (they depend on non-distributable setup data and are useless to distribute at the current stage).  The first approach runs into horrible `ImportMismatchError`s and the second one can work if I add `{toxinidir}/tests` in addition to "." as an argument to `pytest` (after letting `tox` chdir), but it splits the coverage data in different virtualenvs and combining them requires extra processing.

Comment: @CongMa I'm not using `coverage`, but just `pytest --doctest-modules {envsitepackagesdir}/my_package` works for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved the import mismatch:

```
$ pytest tests/ --doctest-modules --pyargs myrootpkg <other args>
```

The problem here is that once you start specifying source paths explicitly (in this case via `--pyargs`), you have to specify all other source paths as well (`tests/` in this example) as `pytest` will stop scanning the rootdir. This shouldn't be an issue when using the `src` layout though, as the tests aren't usually scattered around the repository.